# how to split single txt file into multiple txt files by Python

Tags: python

I have one single txt file, i would like to split it into many files according to the *TEXT ID

for example: the single txt file looks like this

```
*TEXT 017 01/04/63 PAGE 020
THE ALLIES AFTER NASSAU IN DECEMBER 1960, THE U.S . FIRST
PROPOSED TO HELP NATO DEVELOP ITS OWN NUCLEAR STRIKE FORCE . BUT EUROPE.....
*TEXT 018 01/04/63 PAGE 021
RUSSIA WHO'S IN CHARGE HERE ? IT WAS IN 1954 THAT NIKITA
KHRUSHCHEV LAUNCHED HIS GRANDIOSE " VIRGIN LANDS " GAMBLE . PART OF THE.....
*TEXT 019 01/04/63 PAGE 021
BERLIN ONE LAST RUN HANS WEIDNER HAD BEEN HOPING FOR MONTHS TO
ESCAPE DRAB EAST GERMANY AND MAKE HIS WAY TO THE WEST . THE ODDS WERE
AGAINST HIM, FOR WEIDNER, 40, WAS A....
```

how to split into  multiple txt files??

```
filename:
TEXT017.txt

filename:
TEXT018.txt

filename:
TEXT019.txt
```

Comment: look into the `re.split()` method

Comment: What have you tried?  At which point did you have trouble?  Splitting the text?  Writing files?  Reading file?

Comment: @SonofaBeach i do not know how to save the txt to multiple txt files accordingly

Comment: You are going to need to be more specific than that.  What code have you got so far, and how far through the process have you got?  Post your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

inspired by @n1c9 , I modified and added something to make it completed.

```
import re

raw_string = """*TEXT 017 01/04/63 PAGE 020
THE ALLIES AFTER NASSAU IN DECEMBER 1960, THE U.S . FIRST
PROPOSED TO HELP NATO DEVELOP ITS OWN NUCLEAR STRIKE FORCE . BUT EUROPE.....
*TEXT 018 01/04/63 PAGE 021
RUSSIA WHO'S IN CHARGE HERE ? IT WAS IN 1954 THAT NIKITA
KHRUSHCHEV LAUNCHED HIS GRANDIOSE " VIRGIN LANDS " GAMBLE . PART OF THE.....
*TEXT 019 01/04/63 PAGE 021
BERLIN ONE LAST RUN HANS WEIDNER HAD BEEN HOPING FOR MONTHS TO
ESCAPE DRAB EAST GERMANY AND MAKE HIS WAY TO THE WEST . THE ODDS WERE
AGAINST HIM, FOR WEIDNER, 40, WAS A...."""

split_strings = re.split('\n?(\*TEXT .*)\n', raw_string)
blocks = [s for s in split_strings if s] # filter some blank strings

for i in range(0, len(blocks), 2):
    # extract `019` from `*TEXT 019 01/04/63 PAGE 021`
    num = re.search('TEXT (\d+)', blocks[i]).group(1)

    # save content to `TEXT019.txt`
    filename = 'TEXT%s.txt' % num
    content = blocks[i+1]
    with open(filename, 'w+') as fp:
        fp.write(content)
```

Answer (score 2):

Split the text file into lines by what demarcates the beginning of a new text ID:

```
import re

raw_string = """*TEXT 017 01/04/63 PAGE 020
THE ALLIES AFTER NASSAU IN DECEMBER 1960, THE U.S . FIRST
PROPOSED TO HELP NATO DEVELOP ITS OWN NUCLEAR STRIKE FORCE . BUT EUROPE.....
*TEXT 018 01/04/63 PAGE 021
RUSSIA WHO'S IN CHARGE HERE ? IT WAS IN 1954 THAT NIKITA
KHRUSHCHEV LAUNCHED HIS GRANDIOSE " VIRGIN LANDS " GAMBLE . PART OF THE.....
*TEXT 019 01/04/63 PAGE 021
BERLIN ONE LAST RUN HANS WEIDNER HAD BEEN HOPING FOR MONTHS TO
ESCAPE DRAB EAST GERMANY AND MAKE HIS WAY TO THE WEST . THE ODDS WERE
AGAINST HIM, FOR WEIDNER, 40, WAS A...."""

split_string = re.split('(.*TEXT .*PAGE \d+)', raw_string)
for item in split_stuff:
    print('------')
    print(item)

------
*TEXT 017 01/04/63 PAGE 020
------

THE ALLIES AFTER NASSAU IN DECEMBER 1960, THE U.S . FIRST
PROPOSED TO HELP NATO DEVELOP ITS OWN NUCLEAR STRIKE FORCE . BUT EUROPE.....

------
*TEXT 018 01/04/63 PAGE 021
------

RUSSIA WHO'S IN CHARGE HERE ? IT WAS IN 1954 THAT NIKITA
KHRUSHCHEV LAUNCHED HIS GRANDIOSE " VIRGIN LANDS " GAMBLE . PART OF THE.....

------
*TEXT 019 01/04/63 PAGE 021
------

BERLIN ONE LAST RUN HANS WEIDNER HAD BEEN HOPING FOR MONTHS TO
ESCAPE DRAB EAST GERMANY AND MAKE HIS WAY TO THE WEST . THE ODDS WERE
AGAINST HIM, FOR WEIDNER, 40, WAS A....
```

Comment: I mean save the "THE ALLIES AFTER NASSAU IN DECEMBER 1960, THE U.S . FIRST PROPOSED TO HELP NATO DEVELOP ITS OWN NUCLEAR STRIKE FORCE . BUT EUROPE....."  into file name as "TEXT017.txt".